# Matchmaking system N vs N from list

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, arraylist, foreach

I'm trying to make a matchmaking system...
how it will work?

Connected users will appear in the list and later they will randomly picked like:
 **3 vs 3** etc. depending on even number of players

I've got something like this

List with nicknames :

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Bob", "Michael", "Adrian", "Daniel", "Denzel", "Peter" }; //etc
```

Later I'm trying to pick them from list:

```
  foreach (var item in list.OrderBy(f => Guid.NewGuid()).Distinct().Take(list.Count() / 2 ))
    {
     Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

Now it will list 3 of them randomly ,but how can I list the next nicks that would output something like:

Denzel Michael Peter
vs
Daniel Bob Adrian

Comment: You're better off just shuffling the list and then picking the first N followed by another N and so on. Separate the randomizing from the selecting. Like a deck of cards. You shuffle the deck and then you just play them in their new randomized order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Bob", "Michael", "Adrian", "Daniel", "Denzel", "Peter" }; //etc
    var milist = list.OrderBy(f => Guid.NewGuid()).Distinct().ToList();
    string firstTeam = "";
    foreach (var item in milist.Take(list.Count() / 2))
    {
        firstTeam += item + ", ";
    }
    firstTeam = firstTeam.Substring(0, firstTeam.Length - 2);
    string secondTeam = "";
    foreach (var item in milist.Skip(list.Count() / 2))
    {
        secondTeam += item + ", ";
    }
    secondTeam = secondTeam.Substring(0, secondTeam.Length - 2);
    Console.WriteLine(firstTeam + " vs " + secondTeam);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

just make sure the number of players it's an even number.